# Expand a date range to individual date as excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Given a date range I need an excel arrayformula that give the dates between and including the date range, like:-

```
Date From       Date to         Date List 
17 August 2015  19 August 2015  17 August 2015  18 August 2015  19 August 2015
```

There are various answers on here that give a macro of doing this which I dont want to use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. How is your data laid out? What do you want to do with the Array Formula? Have you looked into Array Formulas yourself?

Comment: To belabour the point - let's say you have start date Jan 1, and end date Jan 31. If you want to look at a date in column A, and pick up the value in column B if it is within that date, the answer could be as simple as =IF(AND(A1<Jan 31, A1> Jan1), B1, "")

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF($A$1+COLUMNS($A:A)-1>$B$1,"",$A$1+COLUMNS($A:A)-1)
```

and copy across:

[image]